# async uses a threadpool?

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, stdasync

I am new to C++ and I tried using std::async with launch::async to spawn new threads to handle incoming UDP packets. For every new request on a particular port, async spawns a new thread to handle it.

Under load, I find that the udp packets were reaching me but it takes more than 10 seconds for async to spawn a thread and start processing the information. I was wondering if there is an underlying threadpool and that is the reason, async is blocked and is waiting. If yes, how can I increase the size of this thread pool?

Comment: 10 seconds is a ridiculous amount of time to spawn a thread, you are probably hitting some kind of limit on OS resources. As an aside I would recommend looking at [boost.ASIO](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) for an excellent library to use for task based parallelism and networking and one which has been proposed for inclusion in the standard.

Comment: I added more instrumentation to the code and identified that the issue was not with async. After the poll, the packet was picked for processing only after 10 seconds. I still dont understand why there was a huge delay for the poll in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the standard `std::async` cannot use a thread pool because of the requirements on thread local storage. However in practice MSVC does use a thread pool as it's implementation is built on top of PPL and they simply ignore the requirements on thread local storage. Other implementation will launch a new thread for every call to `std::async` as the language requires.

As ever Bartosz has an excellent [blog post](http://bartoszmilewski.com/2011/10/10/async-tasks-in-c11-not-quite-there-yet/) on this subject.